# specify time range using request-html when scraping a dynamic page

Tags: python, web-scraping, request

I'm recently scraping soccer results for a friend, and it gets me. Below is the link:

https://www.mlssoccer.com/mlsnext/schedule/2021-2022/u16_mls-next-schedule

I'm trying to switch from `selenium` to `request-html`. The very reason that I use `selenium` in the first place is that is the only option I know to **click the calendar**.

[image]

The default date is the current date, but I need all the match history, is it possible to change the default date using `request-html`, if so, how?

Thanks in advance for your time and effort, any useful suggestion is appreciated.

---------------------------- **EDIT**------------------------------

After searching for a while, I find the following possible way to do this using `request-html`,

```
url= "https://www.modular11.com/public_schedule/league/get_matches"
session = HTMLSession()
response = session.post(url, data={"start_date": "2021-10-30 00:00:00"})
print(response.url)
# print(response.text)
response.html.render(timeout=1200)
print(response.html.text)
Please select the gender, league & age of the matches you are looking for.
$(function () { // Fix event duplicate $('.main_row').unbind('click'); $('.main_row').on('click', function () { $(this) .find('button.icon') .children('span') .toggleClass('glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down') .toggleClass('glyphicon glyphicon-menu-up'); if ($(this).find('button.icon span').hasClass('glyphicon-menu-down')) { $(this) .closest('.container-row') .find('.table-row-heading') .addClass('hidden-mobile'); $(this) .closest('.container-row') .find('.table-content-row') .addClass('hidden-xs hidden-sm'); $(this).css({ 'background-color': 'inherit', 'color': '#0B0B33' }); $(this) .closest('.container-row') .find('.mobile-scrolling') .removeClass('hide-scrolling'); } else if ($(this).find('button.icon span').hasClass('glyphicon-menu-up')) { $(this) .closest('.container-row') .find('.table-row-heading') .removeClass('hidden-mobile'); $(this) .closest('.container-row') .find('.table-content-row') .removeClass('hidden-xs hidden-sm'); $(this).css({ 'background-color': '#2A3851', 'color': '#EEEEEE !important' }); $(this) .closest('.container-row') .find('.mobile-scrolling') .addClass('hide-scrolling'); } }); });
```

but it seems like the `data` part has not been send to the server correctly, thus returning:

[image]

instead of (https://www.modular11.com/schedule?year=14):
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the calendar makes an xhr request (that you can monitor with the network tab of your browser web tools), with an easy to customize query dict. the request returns html data that you'll have to parse with beautiful soup

```
import requests
query_dict={'open_page': ['0'], 'academy': ['0'], 'league': ['12'], 'gender': ['1'], 'age': ['["14"]'], 'brackets': ['null'], 'groups': ['null'], 'group': ['null'], 'match_number': ['0'], 'status': ['scheduled'], 'match_type': ['2'], 'schedule': ['0'], 'start_date': ['2021-11-03 00:00:00'], 'end_date': ['2021-11-10 23:59:00']}
r = requests.post('https://www.modular11.com/public_schedule/league/get_matches', data = query_dict)
print(r.text)
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. Can you check the edited post about why `post` using `request-html` fail to render?

Comment: that's another question, revert back and ask a new one